# Codeigniter not loading other controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a controller named `Sign` and I have run the controller using this link:

http://localhost/ci/index.php/sign .

But it is giving `404 error`.

My controller name is: `Sign.php` and below is code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Sign extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "1";
    }
}
```

Please help me to find the error.....

Default page is working fine. But if I change `$route['default_controller'] = 'Sign';` then also 404 error

Comment: Where is controller file placed? Make sure it is `/application/controllers/`.

Comment: @IndianGirl  application/config/routes.php in this file name the default controller name to Sign like $route['default_controller'] = "Sign";

Comment: @SunilPachlangia , but this is not default controller. This is another controller I want to use

Comment: @IndianGirl If this is not default controller then you have to access this via some other controller's function

Comment: @SunilPachlangia can you give an example plz

Comment: Is there a route for `$route['sign'] = 'Sign/index';`? A route will need to be added for it to know where to go

Comment: Don't need, codeigniter resolve in this way, if the route is not defined: `controller/method/parameters`.

Comment: Hmmm...everything looks fine. You shouldn't need to add any Routes to see the index page (index is the default method CI will look for). `/sign` should work. Do you have anything in your Routes file at the minute?

Comment: Is the default welcome page is working? If you not deleted yet from the routes and controllers...: `http://localhost/ci/index.php`. Could be a htaccess issue too

Comment: Yes default page is working fine.

Comment: @Craig Default page is working fine. But if I change $route['default_controller'] = 'Sign'; then also 404 error

Comment: Enable logging and check the log files. From what I can see, everything should work.

Comment: CI's default welcome controller is really Working?

Comment: @Craig log file giving below msg:

ERROR - 2015-09-23 12:43:30 --> 404 Page Not Found: Sign/index

Answer (score 2):

I experienced same issue and I resolved it calling the controller with the first letter in uppercase, in your case Sign.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use following url. Controller names are case sensitive

```
http://localhost/ci/index.php/Sign
```

Comment: I think only Class and File names are case sensitive. Not the URI.